# invalid lvalue in assignment performing the assignment

Tags: c++

Here is the code snippet.

```
char *arguments[ARGSIZE];
char *buf;
//Put stuff in buf and do whatever until
*arguments++ = buf;
```

It seems *arguments++ is throwing the error, why isn't this valid?

Comment: `arguments` is an array, you can't do `++` on an array. Use a pointer instead.

Comment: I thought *arguments[] the same as **arguments, so ++ would move the pointer to the next location in the array. I tried this in another file and it seems to work fine.

Comment: No arrays are not the same as pointers, only similar. Probably in the other file, your 'array' was a function parameter. In C++ if you decalre an array as a function parameter then really it is a pointer. You cannot have array parameters in C++.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Sounds like you should make it a new question on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need such iteration through array then additional pointer is required:

```
char *arguments[ARGSIZE];
char **ptr = &arguments[0];
char *buf;
//Put stuff in buf and do whatever until
*ptr++ = buf;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're code is like below:

```
int a[10];
a++; // error: lvalue required as increment operand
```

You can not apply operator `++` on an array. Make a pointer to an array and then increment that pointer.

```
char **p = &arguments[0];
*p++ = buf;
```